# How to create increment number on foreach

Tags: php, laravel

i try to make auto increment number but my auto increment number start from number six
can you help me please

```
@php $i = 0 @endphp
@foreach ($submited as $tugas)
    @if ($sub->id == $tugas->submit_id) 
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $i }}</</td>
            <td>{{$tugas->nama}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/kelas1/matematika/submit/download/{{$tugas->file}}" class="link-secondary"><i class="fas fa-file-download"> {{$tugas->file}}</i></a>
            </td>
            @if ($tugas->created_at->isBefore($sub->bataswaktu))
                <td class="table-success">On time</td>
            @else
                <td class="table-danger">Late</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endif
    @php
    $i++ 
    @endphp
@endforeach
```

but my output code run from number six:
[MY output code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaxkC.png)

Comment: Can you please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68470629/edit) your output code as text instead of an image to keep the question understandable even if the image is deleted?

Comment: The `$i++` should be _inside_ the `if` block, otherwise you are incrementing the counter for every record that you _don’t_ output as well …

Comment: You should try placing the increment of $i before the @endif like below. Your code will increment the value in all the loops, it should only increment where the condition matches.

Comment: @mickmackusa dunno whether that qualifies as typo, or more as a logical error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable) to completely avoid your `@php` blocks:

```
@foreach ($submited as $tugas)
    @if ($sub->id == $tugas->submit_id) 
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->index + 6 }}</</td>
            <td>{{$tugas->nama}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="/kelas1/matematika/submit/download/{{$tugas->file}}" class="link-secondary"><i class="fas fa-file-download"> {{$tugas->file}}</i></a>
            </td>
            @if ($tugas->created_at->isBefore($sub->bataswaktu))
                <td class="table-success">On time</td>
            @else
                <td class="table-danger">Late</td>
            @endif
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: They don’t want to add 6 to the index. And this will likely not solve their problem to begin with, because the loop index will keep increasing no matter whether the current record actually gets output or skipped, but the way I am reading the question, they want a continuous counter for all record that actually get shown.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understood that differently.

Comment: thanks bro i have fixed it

Answer (score -1):

You should try placing the increment of $i before the @endif like below. Your code will increment the value in all the loops, it should only increment where the condition matches. Example below

```
@php $i = 0 @endphp
   @foreach ($submited as $tugas)
      @if ($sub->id == $tugas->submit_id) 
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ $i }}</</td>
                        <td>{{$tugas->nama}}</td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="/kelas1/matematika/submit/download/{{$tugas->file}}" class="link-secondary"><i class="fas fa-file-download"> {{$tugas->file}}</i></a>
                        </td>
                        @if ($tugas->created_at->isBefore($sub->bataswaktu))
                            <td class="table-success">On time</td>
                        @else
                            <td class="table-danger">Late</td>
                        @endif
                      </tr>
@php $i++ @endphp
@endif
@endforeach
```